# CRISPR Knock in

Tags: molecular-biology, molecular-genetics, gene, transformation, crispr

Using the CRISPR/Cas9 technology, it is possible that after inducing a DSB with the Cas9 endonuclease guided with an RNA designed by the user and using a template DNA, get a desired Knock-In (KI) by homologous recombination.

I have read that for desired KI-s that are less than 200 bp, a olygonucleatide should be enough as template. On the contrary, if the desired KI is bigger than that, a plasmid vector should be used.

Is that information accurate and correct? and, where is the upper limit for the KI length?

Comment: Successful knock-in of 1000 bp and 500 bp has been done before. ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5307959/